# Can I build auto-firing guns with ScriptCraft in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft, scriptcraft

I am reading https://github.com/walterhiggins/ScriptCraft/blob/master/docs/YoungPersonsGuideToProgrammingMinecraft.md and want to try it out with my son.

I see there is a list of events available, though, being new to this mod, I am not sure I can implement what I am thinking of.

Say, I have a territory around my castle, say, square of 300x300 blocks on a plain field. I know the coordinates of the square.

Now, can I track if any mob intersects the bounds from outside to inside?

If it's possible, what's the event I should look for?

Then, can I add some mechanism that would through something in the direction of the mob's position? How could it look like? Or, even just signalling that a mob is in the zone.

Generally, I want to track mobs and do perform some actions for events.

Comment: http://jabelarminecraft.blogspot.nl/p/minecraft-forge-172-event-handling.html I don't know which forge version you're planning to use, but this one has a nice list of the available forge events.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, kudos for exploring this with your son.

I wish I could provide exacting details, but my familiarity with ScriptCraft is limited. However, given that is based on Spigot (not Forge, as suggested in the comments), I can provide an answer from that perspective. I’ll leave the nitty-gritty details of accessing POJOs to your expertise with JavaScript.

While player movements fire `PlayerMoveEvent` events, there is no corresponding event for other entities/mobs. If there were, it would be a matter of checking whether an entity’s location has breached your perimeter and handling it accordingly.

The simplest approach would be to define a function that calls `getLivingEntities()` on a [World](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/World.html), iterator over the list to determine the type of entity and perform whatever actions are desired; say, announce that it has breached your barrier. This function would be registered as a scheduled task with the [BukkitScheduler](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html) as a repeating synchronous task. I found this [example](https://dullahansoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/using-the-bukkit-scheduler-in-scriptcraft/) for scheduling a task, though it is for a single delayed asynchronous task.

```
load(__folder + "../drone/drone.js");
load(__folder + "../core/scriptcraft.js");

Drone.extend("big",function(){
  server.scheduler.scheduleAsyncDelayedTask(global.plugin,function(){
        (new Drone()).box(1,500,100,500);
        print("done");
    });
});
```

On a large server with many entities, the approach would be optimized by accessing each [Chunk](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Chunk.html) containing the protected area and retrieving entities contained therein with `getEntities()`.